# Can diamondback nodes communicate with cturtle nodes?

Tags: ros, cturtle, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can diamondback nodes communicate with cturtle nodes ? If yes, then  ill it work with roscore from cturtle or must I use roscore from diamondback?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9173/can-diamondback-nodes-communicate-with-cturtle-nodes-?/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, I've successfully run a cturtle computer along with a diamondback computer. However, if any of the messages you're using have changed between versions, you'll get errors.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1